# Open source dataset (manufacturing, machine operations)

Tags: classification, dataset, sensors

I am looking for an open source dataset from the manufacturing domain (sensor data, time series) with specific traits. It should stem from a process consisting of a sequence of distinct machine operations (arbitrary example:  drilling - injecting - polishing - drilling) and those should be labelled if possible.

I was hoping that one of you is aware of such a dataset and could give me a hint.

Thank you.